Alternative solution: if $f(x, y) = (mx+y, 2x+my)$ is surjective, what is $m$?

$\begin{align} f: \mathbb{R^2} &\to \mathbb{R^2}  \\ (x,y) &\mapsto (mx +y, 2x + my) \end{align}$
$f$ is surjective. Find $m$.

Hi, I've just begun my study in linear algebra in college. We've gone over matrices, determinants, inverse matrices, matrix ranks, and systems of linear equations. In the last topic, we've been taught how to determine if a system is consistent based on the rank of the coefficient matrix and the augmented matrix. I attempted to solve this problem but I feel that there might be a better way, or at least a more elegant way to present my solution. I'm looking for some advice. Thank you very much!

Let $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ be arbitrary.
Consider the system of equations: $$\begin{cases}mx + y = u \\2x+ my = v\end{cases}$$which can be written in matrix form as $$\begin{pmatrix}m & 1 \\2 & m\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\  y\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} u \\  v\end{pmatrix}$$
We have $\det{A} = m^2 - 2$ for $A = \begin{pmatrix}m & 1 \\2 & m\end{pmatrix}$.
Since $A$ is a square matrix, for $\det{A} \neq 0$ or $m\neq \pm\sqrt{2}$, the system is Cramer and thus always has a unique solution.
For $m = \sqrt{2}$, we consider the augmented matrix $$\overline{A} = \begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{2} & 1 & u \\ 2 & \sqrt{2} & v\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} r_1}\begin{pmatrix}1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 2 & \sqrt{2} & v\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{-2 r_1+r_2 \to r_2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 & 0 & v - u\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$$ For $m = -\sqrt{2}$, we consider the augmented matrix $$\overline{A} = \begin{pmatrix}-\sqrt{2} & 1 & u \\ 2 & -\sqrt{2} & v\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} r_1}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 2 & -\sqrt{2} & v\end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{-2 r_1+r_2 \to r_2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0 & 0 & v + u\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$$In both cases, $\text{rank}{\overline{A}} = 2 > \text{rank}{A} = 1$, for $v \neq \pm u\sqrt{2}$. Thus, the system is inconsistent for some values of $u,v$.
Therefore, the system is consistent for $m \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{\pm\sqrt{2}\}$.

Your method is good, just a remark, the fact that rank $A$ < 2 means that the column space of the matrix does not covers the whole codomain, i.e., that the image of $f$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e., it is not surjective. That is a more elegant way to say it.
You could also prove that the kernel of $f$ is non-trivial, i.e., let
$$ ker(f)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:f(x,y)=(0,0)\} $$
If $m=\sqrt{2}$, you will find that this subspace $ker(f)$ has dimension 1, then since
$$ dim(\mathbb{R}^2)= dim(ker(f))+dim(Im(f)) $$
this would mean that that $f$ is not surjective because $dim(Im(f))<2$, remember that $dim(Im(f))= rank(A)$.
Also $Im(f)$ is the column space.
